# how to change the look and feel for Qt form?

Tags: qt, coding-style, stylesheet, look-and-feel

i need to change my form look and feel and i dont know :
what i need to download and install ?
is there any ready to use look and feel installed into qt library ?
i am using windows and qt 4.4.3

Comment: Re-tagged with stylesheet and style since that is what they are called in Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Widget Styles](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/widgets-styles.html) and [Stylesheets](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/widgets-stylesheet.html) (both linked to Qt 4.4 since that's your version).

Edit: In other words, you don't need to install anything else.  Styles are built into Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Look-and-feel is pretty vague -- you can change the GUI application style by adding the `-style STYLENAME` command line argument when you run the program.  You can change to the application to run under `motif`, `windows`, `platinum`, or any other custom styles that you might have compiled (such as `plastique`).

Here is more information about it in the Qt Docs: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qapplication.html#QApplication